# Como eu posso obter um resultado de uma soma de acordo com os itens do meu array?

Tags: javascript, array

Bem, estou à tentar fazer um **algoritmo** que de acordo com os itens do meu **array**, preciso que meu *looping* **for of** busque os itens, e de acordo com cada **item** faça uma soma e me dê o **resultado** que eu preciso.

```js
const resultados = ["V", "E", "V", "E"];
let vitorias = 3;
let empates = 1;
let derrotas = 0;
soma = 0;
for (let pontos of resultados) {

  if (pontos == "V" || pontos == "E" || pontos == "D") {
    soma++

    let pontos = parseInt(vitorias * 3) + parseInt(empates);

    console.log(pontos);

  }

}
```

O **resultado** da  **soma** de acordo com meu array, deveria ser **8**, não sei o que está errado.

Comment: Não faz sentido essa `soma`. Vc precisa de dois contadores: um pra quantidade de vitórias e outro pra quantidade de empates. E no fim, só depois do `for`, calcule a pontuação (qtdVitorias * 3 + qtdEmpates). Outra alternativa: no `for`, some 3 quando for vitória e 1 quando for empate (nesse caso vc não terá a quantidade de cada um, somente o total de pontos - mas se precisa das quantidades, use a primeira opção)

Answer (score 0):

Ao fazer `if (pontos == "V" || pontos == "E" || pontos == "D")` você está aumentando em 1 ponto para todos os casos, para corrigir isso é necessário tratar caso a caso.

O código fica assim:

```
const resultados =["V","E","V","E"];
let vitorias = 3;
let empates = 1;
let derrotas = 0;
soma = 0;

for (let pontos of resultados) {
    if (pontos == "V") {
        soma+=3;
    }
    else if (pontos == "E") {
        soma+=1;
    }
    console.log(soma);
}
```

Como o objetivo é apenas somar os pontos, não é necessário considerar a derrota pois ela não acrescenta (e nem subtrai) em nada nos pontos

Comment: BELEZA Henrique, só que eu só preciso que seja imprimido o número 8, que de acordo com minha array fica assim: Como o time teve 02 vitórias(2x2) e dois empates (2x1), ele tem que ficar com 8 pontos (6+2).

Comment: Então, é só remover o `console.log(soma)` do `for` e coloca-lo logo abaixo, ele irá imprimir no console apenas o valor final da soma

Comment: O resultado do seu código ficou: 3, 4, 7, 8.

Comment: Obrigado Henrique funcionou, eu sou muito iniciante e não tinha essa noção que poderia dar diferença! valeu mesmo cara1

Comment: @JOSICLEYTONALVESBARRETO Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique à vontade para comentar. 

Answer (score -1):

De uma lista contar a quantidade de ocorrência e a partir dessa repetição e apresentar um resultado como vitória derrota e empate.
Do array ["V", "E", "V", "E"], considerando as siglas que repetem contem 2 vitórias 2 empates, derrota seria se vitoria (sigla) não estiver na lista ([ "E",  "E"]) tanto quanto ["E", "V", "E"] sera 1 vitória e 1 derrota e 2 empates.

```
for(let placar of resultados){
    if (placar == 'V'){
        vitorias = vitorias + 1;
    }   
    if (placar == 'E'){
        empates+=1
    }
    
    if(vitorias == 0 ){
        derrotas +=1;
    }
}

console.log('Vitorias  : '+vitorias);
console.log('Empates   : '+empates);
console.log('Derrotas  : '+derrotas);
```

Cada vez que a sigla **V** ou **E** repetir a variável **vitoria** e **empate** é incrementado 1. Por tanto quanto mais **V** mais ocorrera um incremento e a derrota é contada nessa ida.

a variável somar nesse código não faz sentido, seria essa variável somar para calcular todas as vitórias empates a cada rodada?? ou como principio é diferente.

```
    soma = vitorias + empates;
    console.log('Soma Vitoria e Empates  : '+soma);
```

suponho que as variáveis **vitorias** **empates** e  **derrotas** representam um placar que inicia com zero ao iniciar o código elas mudam dependendo do array.

A exemplo usando forEach que também apresentara o mesmo resultado:

```
resultados.forEach(function(valor,indice){
    if (valor == 'V'){
        vitorias = vitorias + 1;
    }   
    if (valor == 'E'){
        empates+=1
    }
    
    if(vitorias == 0 ){
        derrotas +=1
    }



    });
console.log('Vitorias  : '+vitorias);
console.log('Empates   : '+ empates);
console.log('Derrotas  : '+derrotas);
soma = vitorias + empates;
console.log('Soma Vitoria e Empates  : '+soma);
```